# How to store array of object in react nativr async storage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

> I'm trying to set an array of objects in React Native AsyncStorage.
> However, just the 1st item will store in it.
>
> ```
>       await AsyncStorage.setItem(
>     `${props.index}`,
>     JSON.stringify({
>       data: totalSet,
>       name: props.index,
>       date: today.toISOString().substring(0, 10),
>     })
> ```
>
> the first item (data) is an array

**Update**

In my workout tracker app,
I try to create nested object. in the child component, I have following data:
weight: number
reps: number
result: also number (combination of weight and reps)
setIndex :number, which indicate the index of each sets
I have sent above data to parent component like this:

```
Child component

onPress={() =>
          childToParent({
            setDetails: [
              {
                setIndex: setIndex,
                result: result,
                weight: weight,
                reps: reps,
              },
            ],
          }) + buttonStatus()
```

in the parent, I have given data, and trying to add into exsiting array and also adding 2 more item, date and index of each workout

```
parent component 
const [totalSet, settotalSet] = useState([{ today }, { index }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data != 0) {
      settotalSet((current) => [...current, data]);
    }
  }, [data]);
```

then I store it into asyncstorage

```
const storeData = async () => {
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(
    `${props.index}`,
    JSON.stringify(totalSet)
  ).then((res) => console.log(res));
} catch (e) {
  // saving error
}
};
```

and get it into another component like this

```
getMyObject = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem('1512').then((res) => {
        setData(JSON.parse(res));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // read error
    }
  };
```

Finally as a result, I have below array:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "today": "2022-09-04",
  },
  Object {
    "index": "1512",
  },
  Object {
    "setDetails": Array [
      Object {
        "reps": "3",
        "result": 13.200000000000001,
        "setIndex": 0,
        "weight": "12",
      },
    ],
  },
  Object {
    "setDetails": Array [
      Object {
        "reps": "3",
        "result": 26.400000000000002,
        "setIndex": 1,
        "weight": "24",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

everything is fine, except I need a nested object and this is an array.
How to create such an nested object at the first place?

Comment: what is the response when you do AsyncStorage.getItem(`${props.index}`)

Comment: JSON.stringify({
      data: totalSet,
      name: props.index,
      date: today.toISOString().substring(0, 10),
    })

isnt this only 1 object ? :O

Comment: @enzou the response is an array contain just "totalSet" value

Comment: could yo edit the question and give us the example with more details?, how are you using the getItem method?